# How to display caption at the bottom of a figure

Tags: captions

I am not able to show the caption at the bottom of figure. I always get in the middle. 
I would appreciate your help. Below is the code.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cmll}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amstext, amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit2003}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
{\setlength{\unitlength}{6mm}
\begin{picture}(13,13)(0,0)
\put(-2,-0.5){\framebox(6,3){ What are Pragruhya}}
\put(8,-4){\framebox(7,3.2){
\shortstack{A monosyllabic \\with the exception of }}}
\put(4,1){\vector(1,2){4}}
\put(8,0){\framebox(7,3){
\shortstack{that come\\ after the of }}}
\put(4,1){\vector(1,1){4}}
\put(8,4){\framebox(7,3){
\shortstack{ or \\are called }}}
\put(4,1){\vector(1,-2){4}}
\put(8,-8){\framebox(7,3){
\shortstack{ A ending in \\are called }}}
\put(4,1){\vector(1,-1){4}}
\put(8,8){\framebox(7,4){
\shortstack{ in when \\followed by the \\word in the }}}
\put(4,1){\vector(1,0){4}}
\end{picture}
}
\end{center}
\caption{Some More Sutras}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome!  A formatting tip: begin each of your TeX lines with four spaces—or highlight it and hit the `101010` button, which does the same thing—to preserve the formatting of your code.

Comment: Also, while I must commend you for providing a complete source file, I wish you had also made it *minimal*. As it was, it used all sorts of packages that are irrelevant to the problem at hand, and some of which will not even load in a plain latex. Before asking your next question, please try trimming some more fat from your sample files.

Comment: Just a small tip which is especially true when you have collaborators: Whitespace is not your enemy, while having a source file that is a block of continuous text might seem compact(hell you can have the entire document on *one line* ) it makes it completely unreadable to anyone else. Try to put extra lines to seperate code into logical blocks, especially in the header and in areas with heavy markup (like in figure declarations or tables)

Answer (score 3):

You need to tweak the parameters of the picture environment:

```
\begin{picture}(13,21)(-2,-8)
```

I may have gotten it slightly wrong. The first pair is the size of the picture, and the second pair is the coordinates of the bottom left corner. By setting the latter to (0,0) and using negative coordinates, you were drawing outside the box reserved for the picture.